# turn multidimensional array into tree-like structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
[
    {"primary":{"sub":{"ID":[]}}},
    {"primary":{"sub":{"Name":[]}}},
    {"primary":{"ID":[]}},
    {"primary":{"Name":[]}}
]
```

I would like to get the unique properties and sort them into a tree that has the following structure:

```
primary
   sub
      ID
      Name
   ID
   Name
```

I have tried many things, the latest of which was this:

```
function multiDimensionalUnique(arr) {
    var uniques = [];
    var itemsFound = {};
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
      var stringified = JSON.stringify(arr[i]);
      if (itemsFound[stringified]) {
        continue;
      }
      uniques.push(arr[i]);
      itemsFound[stringified] = true;
    }
    return uniques;
}

uniqueCols = multiDimensionalUnique(arrayCols);
```

but that did not work.

I have also looked at grouping functions and reduce (which I cannot manage to wrap my brain around), but have so far not solved it.

It is important to note that the properties are all dynamic, the structure could be very complex and I do not know exactly what data I will get beforehand, just that it will be something like the above code (which is very simplified).

Comment: `array into tree`  Could you define what a tree is?.

Comment: Keith, with tree I mean a tree-like structure as per the example in my code.

Comment: sgiant, yes, but how do I do that? I mean, I can check for uniqueness, but how do I *merge*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recursively called function `dive()` can do the job, see here:

```js
var inp=[{"primary":{"sub":{"ID":[1,2,3]}}},
    {"primary":{"sub":{"Name":[4,5,6]}}},
    {"primary":{"ID":[7,8,9]}},
    {"primary":{"Name":[5,5,5]}}];
var tree={};


function dive(tree,obj){
  for (var p in obj) {
    if (!tree[p]) tree[p]=obj[p];
    else     dive(tree[p],obj[p]);
  }
}

inp.forEach((el)=>dive(tree,el));

console.log(tree);
```

I took the liberty of *beefing up* your empty arrays with some contents. It will work just as well with empty arrays of course.

result:

```
{
  "primary": {
    "sub": {
      "ID": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      "Name": [
        4,
        5,
        6
      ]
    },
    "ID": [
      7,
      8,
      9
    ],
    "Name": [
      5,
      5,
      5
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for, and it's so simple :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* provided input */
const array= [
    {"primary":{"sub":{"ID":[]}}},
    {"primary":{"sub":{"Name":[]}}},
    {"primary":{"ID":[]}},
    {"primary":{"Name":[]}}
]
/* expected output 
    primary
   sub
      ID
      Name
   ID
   Name
*/

const recursivelyPushPropertyNames=  function (o, aggregated) {
  for (let p in o) {
    if ("object" === typeof o[p] && !Array.isArray(o[p])) {
        if (!(p in aggregated)) {
        aggregated[p]= []
      }
      recursivelyPushPropertyNames(o[p], aggregated[p])
    }

    if (0 > aggregated.indexOf(p)) {
      aggregated.push(p)
    }
  }

  console.log("Step 1.B: recursivelyPushPropertyNames(o, aggregated) "/* , aggregated */ )
}
const aggregate= function (arr) {
    const aggregated = []
  for (let i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    recursivelyPushPropertyNames(arr[i], aggregated)            
  }
  console.log("Step 1.A: aggregate(arr) ", aggregated )
  return aggregated
}

const indent = function (str, tabcount) {
    let c=0, t="";
  while (c++ < tabcount) {
    t= t.concat('\t')
  }
  return t.concat(str)
}
const displayKeys= function (aggregatedList, tabcount) {
  let output= ""
  tabcount= tabcount || 0
    numeric: for (let i=0; i < aggregatedList.length; i++) {
    if ( aggregatedList[i] in aggregatedList ) {
        output= output.concat(
        indent(aggregatedList[i], tabcount),
        '\n',
        displayKeys(
            aggregatedList[ aggregatedList[i] ],
            1 + tabcount
        )
      )
    }
    else {
        output= output.concat(
        indent(aggregatedList[i], tabcount),
        '\n'
      )
    }
  }
  console.log("Step 2: displayKeys(aggregatedList, tabcount)\n", output)
  return output
}

// - All done done
console.log(
    displayKeys(
    aggregate(array)
  )
)
```